# Alternate cases in textbox Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textbox

I want to make a piece of code that alternates the case of text that the user inputs.  Currently, my code looks like this:

```
var num;

function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
}

$('input, textarea').onkeyup(function () {
    prev = true;
    for (num = 0; num < this.length; num += 2)
    {
        this.substr(num).val(toTitleCase(this.substr(num)));
    }
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't work (as in nothing changes).  I tried making it a Chrome extension but it doesn't change the case.  Is it my way of testing the code that's weird or does the code have a bug?

Comment: Remove `onkeyup` and use just `keyup`

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: `this.length` will be undefined each time, use `this.value.length` or cache `$(this)` and then work on it

Comment: @A.J `substr` is also a method  **knowledge alert

Comment: @siam , yeah my bad. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Simple code. [Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/shahabaz/pen/ygxoqm)

```
$('input, textarea').keyup(function () {
 var value = $(this).val();
 var altText = '';
 for (num = 0; num < value.length; num ++)
 {
    if(num%2==0)
      altText += value[num].toUpperCase();
    else
      altText += value[num].toLowerCase();
 }
 $(this).val(altText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Below code should work

var num;

function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
}

$('input, textarea').keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var char = value.slice(-1);
    if(value.length%2){
        var str2 = value.slice(0, -1) + toTitleCase(char);
        $(this).val(str2);
    }
 });
```